# I want to convert csv to json with key value pair

Tags: json

I have a JSON file as below  and want to convert to json with Name key , value pair ,
Eg :  "name":"emailAddress",
"value" :"Trest22@gmail.com"
If have multiple JSON tags then it should break into separate tag as shown in image.

Please help

```
[
  {
    "emailAddress": "Trest22@gmail.com",
    "loginName": "Testinguser222",
    "firstName": "Test222",
    "surName": "Test22",
    "primaryPhone": "",
    "companyId": 123445,
    "extracompanies": "[12311,33333]",
    "middleName": "Test",
    "mobilePhone": 6666666666,
    "fax": 87687687686
    
  }
  
]
```

Want to convert as below

```
{
            {
                "name":"emailAddress",
                "value" :"Trest22@gmail.com"
            }
                {
                "name":"loginName",
                "value":"Testinguser222"
            }
            {
                "name":"firstName",
                "value":"Test222"
            }
            {
                "name":"surName",
                "value":"Test22"
            }
            {   "name":"extracompanies",
                "value": "[12311,33333]"    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see the csv file content, are you asking how to convert an array of object to a single independent object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if any library can do that, however, in Java, you can achieve it as shown below,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String test = "{\n" +
                    "    \"emailAddress\": \"Trest22@gmail.com\",\n" +
                    "    \"loginName\": \"Testinguser222\",\n" +
                    "    \"firstName\": \"Test222\",\n" +
                    "    \"surName\": \"Test22\",\n" +
                    "    \"primaryPhone\": \"\",\n" +
                    "    \"companyId\": 123445,\n" +
                    "    \"extracompanies\": \"[12311,33333]\",\n" +
                    "    \"middleName\": \"Test\",\n" +
                    "    \"mobilePhone\": 6666666666,\n" +
                    "    \"fax\": 87687687686\n" +
                    "    \n" +
                    "  }";

            Map<String, Object> maps = mapper.readValue(test, Map.class);
            List<Map<String,Object>> converted = maps.keySet().stream().map(key -> {
                Map<String,Object> internalMap = new HashMap<>();
                internalMap.put("name", key);
                internalMap.put("value", maps.get(key));
                return internalMap;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(converted);
```

Output

```
[{"name":"emailAddress","value":"Trest22@gmail.com"},{"name":"loginName","value":"Testinguser222"},{"name":"firstName","value":"Test222"},{"name":"surName","value":"Test22"},{"name":"primaryPhone","value":""},{"name":"companyId","value":123445},{"name":"extracompanies","value":"[12311,33333]"},{"name":"middleName","value":"Test"},{"name":"mobilePhone","value":6666666666},{"name":"fax","value":87687687686}]
```